# Silverlight DataGrid vertical scrollbar issue

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, scroll

I have a DataGrid in my silverlight application and I'm wondering how to get the same behavior for the vertical scrolling as the horizontal scrolling.  When I resize the browser horizontally, The app will bunch up all the controls and the horizontal scrollbar will appear, however when I resize it vertially, the controls at the bottom of the app just move out of view.  Does anyone know any tricks to handle something like this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My problem is StackPanels.  Don't use them, they are evil and don't resize.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the scrollbar to show up at all with the datagrid.  Removing the datagrid from a stackpanel and using a grid instead also solved my problem.

Good call!

Answer (score 1):

In my case the Height of the rowdefinition where I have the datagrid was set to "Auto" and it had a rowdefinition below with height set to *. I switched the values and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes stack panels causes some unknown errors in Silverlight, I Had also experienced problems with regards to stack panels like nesting data fields inside stack panels which are also inside data forms.